# How to solve "cuDNN is not enabled"

Tags: python, chainer, cupy

I'm using cupy with Spyder3.3.6 and Python 3.7.5 in Windows machine(Win10 Pro 64bit, i7-7700, 8GBMemory, GTX-1060-6GB).
Version of cupy, chainer, cuda and cuDNN are 6.0.0, 5.3.0, 10.1.243, and 7.6.4,respectively.

When I import cupy, this error has occured:

```
C:\Users\(username)\Anaconda3\envs\gpgpu\lib\site-packages\chainer\backends\cuda.py:98: UserWarning: cuDNN is not enabled.
Please reinstall CuPy after you install cudnn
(see https://docs-cupy.chainer.org/en/stable/install.html#install-cudnn).
  'cuDNN is not enabled.\n'
```

However, try

```
import cupy
```

again, the error hasn't occur and cupy works well.
(i.e. write "import cupy" 2 time in the code)
However cupy is actually working, it fells strange to me.
I already tried to re-install related packages, but the problem hasn't solved.

How I can solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it seems you are using different versions of chainer/cupy. 
We recommend chainer and cupy to match the version number as we develop them in tandem.

How did you install CuPy? 
We support pre-built wheels for windows, which include cudnn and nccl versions that we guarantee to work. You can install them with `pip install cupy-cuda101`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.<br>
I installed CuPy from conda. Can I install pre-vuilt wheels for windows via conda instead of pip?

Comment: Conda builds do not include cudnn binaries and they resort to the conda dependence. Also, chainer versions in conda are outdated. At this moment we recommend installing chainer/cupy using pip if possible. 

You can always try to build cupy and chainer from source if pip is not an option.